# Imported typescript object does not has the property

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am using nodeJs with Typescript:

This is what I have in dbconfig.ts

```
interface DatabaseConfig {
  username: string;
  password: string;
  database: string;
  host: string;
  dialect: string;
  port?: number;
  logging?: boolean | Function;
  force?: boolean;
  timezone?: string;
}

interface DatabaseConfigs {
  development: DatabaseConfig,
  staging: DatabaseConfig,
  production: DatabaseConfig
}

 var configs: DatabaseConfigs = {
  development: {
    username: "postgres",
    password: "password",
    database: "development",
    host: "localhost",
    dialect: "postgres"
  },
  staging: {
    dialect: "postgres",
    database: "development",
    username: "postgres",
    password: "password",
    host: "localhost"
  },
  production: {
    dialect: "postgres",
    database: "development",
    username: "postgres",
    password: "password",
    host: "localhost"
  }
};

export default configs;
```

When I import this file in config.ts like this:

```
import * as sequelizeConfig from './dbconfig';
```

and then in the same file try to access

```
sequelizeConfig.production;
```

TS raises an error saying:

> [ts] Property 'production' does not exist on type 'typeof
>   "filepath/dbconf"'.

I have already declared the interface and type of variable `configs` that I am exporting. I don't understand why I am still getting this error.

The only constraint I have here is that dbconfig.ts has to export the configs object directly and not in some property on export. I am facing the same issue in other files as well. What is the right way of importing and exporting files in TS?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have export `default`:

```
export default configs
```

But your import statement `import * as sequelizeConfig from './dbconfig';` is wrong. The correct import for default export you would:

```
import sequelizeConfig from './dbconfig';
```

## More

Personally I would not recommend defaults : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/defaultIsBad.html

Comment: That's really dumb of me. Not posting any more questions on Stack overflow until I finish reading the mentioned book. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @basarat may you update your link? It no longer works.